# How to start a Linux (RHEL 6.8) based GUI application on boot

Tags: gui, application, autostart

I am trying to auto start MeatGrinder GUI application on boot.

I have small script which will invoke the application. My requirement is to auto trigger the script on boot.

Here is my script-

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cd /root/tools/LinuxMG_2.610_x86-64
 ./MG -start -ini=ci-fit.ini -nologo
```

I have tried crontab (also tried sleeping for 60s before executing cron job), `chkconfig` and `/etc/init.d`, but none of them invoking the GUI application.

`gnome-session-properties` (startup application properties) will auto start application only after user logs in, but not on boot.

Please let me know if there is any way to invoke GUI applications on boot.

Comment: What is your DM/DE? Many DE now have a way to auto-start.